# Measuring HTML parsing time in web browsers

Tags: firefox, dom, browser, html-parsing

In my project, I attend to measure the HTML parsing time, that is, **how much percent of processing time is for HTML parsing** when a web browser handling a particular webpage.

It seems instrumenting Firefox would be a good place to start. But this may take some time (I have no idea of the any complexities of instrumenting Firefox to fetch this info).

So my question is: Any idea on measuring this ratio in a relative lightweight way? Or by any chance you saw this information already available on any public papers/websites?

Comment: I don't think there is a plain rate of processing time that you can find on a document or website. I think it will depend on how your html document is structured, it's length, etc. Have you tried using PageSpeed Chrome plugin? I think even Firebug can give you some useful info. YSlow is also a good option to have a look on

Comment: @pollirrata great info!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to benchmark your HTML. Ideally the benchmark tools will give you a varied output cause its basically based on a lot of parameters. Well to get started you can use some online once to bechmark your HTML page. There are many search for HTML Benchmark.

Then you may use the follwing to becnhmark your browser.
http://browsermark.rightware.com/

Well i am sure you may get a relative answer and some numbers to crunch...